# Get JavaScript reference to element created in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to obtain a `<div>` created inside `ng-repeat` so that I can add content inside generated by a third-party library.

Attempt 1:

```
<div ng-init="init()">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div id="{{ item.id }}"></div>
  </div>
</div>

$scope.init = function() {
  for (var i in items) {
    var element = document.getElementById(items[i].id);
    generateInnerHtml(element);
  }
};
```

Attempt 2:

```
<div ng-init="init()">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div id="{{ item.id }}" ng-init="addContent(item.id)"></div>
  </div>
</div>

$scope.addContent = function(id) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  generateInnerHtml(element);
};
```

Attempt 3:

```
<div ng-init="init()">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div id="{{ item.id }}" ng-init="addContent(this)"></div>
  </div>
</div>

$scope.addContent = function(element) {
  generateInnerHtml(element);
};
```

For all three attempts, `element` is always null or undefined. What's wrong?

Comment: Keeping references to DOM elements in controllers would probably fall under the umbrella of angular antipatterns.  Why not put a directive on the elements in the ng-repeat and do whatever DOM level manipulation/referencing you need to do in the directive `link` function?

Answer (score 4):

In attempts #1 and #2 your function is running before all the Angular directives are processed, so the `id` of the `div`s isn't defined yet.

You can wrap your code in `$timeout()` to force it to wait until the DOM is properly generated:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myController", function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.addContent = function(id) {
      $timeout(function() {
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        generateInnerHtml(element);
      }, 0);
    };

})
```

See demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/1w5ntajm/.

Comment: @thegreatjedi this video will clarify it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, your functions are running before the rendering has completed. But leave DOM manipulation to be in a directive as @anied has mentioned. This way, you decouple it from the controller and you can easily re-use it.

See [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6xd9kMESzbOC9WxOX21Q?p=preview)

Markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" data-generated="item"></div>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('generated', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  var generateInnerHtml = function(e) {
    e.innerHTML = '<pre>item = {{vm.item}}</pre>'
  };
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      item: '=generated'
    },
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true,
    controller: [function() {
    }],
    compile: function(element, attr) {
      generateInnerHtml(element[0]);
      return function(scope, element, attr) {
        // Only do this if you need access to scope variables
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```